# np.diff on big-endian data seems slow

Tags: numpy, floating-point, endianness

I am selecting arrays from a fits file like so:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

path = "cube.fits"
f = fits.open(path)
cube = f[0].data

print(cube.shape)

out: (4608, 3072, 3072)
```

I've noticed that the dtype of this cube is big-endian:

```
print(cube.dtype)

out: dtype('>f4')
```

So when I attempt to grab one array from the cube and perform numpy operations, from some stack browsing, I can only assume it's initially converting to little-endian (is that true?). And as such when attempting np.diff, the process seems very slow:

```
test_data = cube[:,np.random.randint(3072),np.random.randint(3072)]
diff_array = np.diff(test_data)
```

Attempting to convert the entire cube using `cube = f[0].data.astype(np.float32)` also seems like it will be an exceptionally long process given how long `diff_array` takes to compute.

Is this common behaviour with no workarounds or am I mishandling these operations entirely and my hypothesis that this is due to endian-ness conversions is incorrect?

Any insight into this would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you check the floating point numbers looks valid (e.g. no sub-normals, NaN, Inf values)? Moreover, your array takes `4608*3072*3072*4 = 162 GiB` of RAM which is really huge. Two resulting arrays will be as big so you need at least 486 GiB of available RAM! Extracting random values for a 162 GiB array is expected to be slow since random DRAM access are much slower than contiguous ones (especially with a sequential code like Numpy).